How to handle setup and nonsetup objects record creation on postinstall script
In managed package we need to install some records on custome objects also when installing we need to add assign permission set to all users, if we do setup and non-setup object creation on same class will given error MIXED_DML_Operation error. Correct me if am wrong in post install script we cant call another apex class. How we can install records and assign permission set using post install script?

You might try using one of the Async Apex constructs. I know you can run Batchable from an install handler so I suspect you can run queueable. You could spawn some Queueables and have each handle only Setup or non-Setup objects.
Disclaimer: I have not tried it.  You'd want to write little test and see if it works.  I use a small managed package for testing out ideas.  It has a few simple objects and code modules in it so it uploads in less than a minute and I can install in a test org without ever listing it. If I'm not sure how a feature will behave in a managed package, I can do a dry run of a simple model in about fifteen minutes.
But, I don't disagree with Renato that there is a limit to how much you want to automate. Particularly with anything regarding permissions including sharing. Let the admin explicitly do grants.

Stop trying to automate everything and let the admin do some of the job.
The appropriate way of doing this is writing a document with instructions on how to use your app, and that includes "installation and configuration" instructions.
You absolutely can have the admin assign the permission sets themselves. And if you wish to make their job easier, you could have a custom page/tab with a screen flow or component, or whatever, that is basically just a button that creates the PermissionSetAssignment records for every active user in the org.
